# How to update maven Project in Intellij in offline modus?

Tags: intellij-idea

How to update maven dependencies in offline modus ? In eclipse Right click on the project -> Maven -> update project -> offline.
where to find this functionality in intellij?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Eclipse and what the operation you mention specifically does. I can tell you how IntelliJ IDEA works with maven offline.

When you toggle into "offline Mode" (via the offline button [image] in the maven tool window), IDEA simply appends the maven `--offline` option to all maven command lines it runs. IDEA will update and import maven projects in the same manner as when you are "online" except that it will report any items that cannot be found in the local repository (See `Working in Offline Mode` in *Help > Language and Framework-Specific Guidelines > Build Tools > Maven*). So to update after a pom change -- regardless if you are in online or offline mode -- just run the reimport function [image] (or let it run automatically if you have "import maven projects automatically" turned on).

Prior to going into offline mode, it is usually helpful to run the maven [dependency:go-offline](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/go-offline-mojo.html) goal. You can either do that by creating a custom Maven Run/debug configuration, or simply running it in the terminal window.